# How to control form field widths in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Given the code below I am trying to figure out the correct way to display the form fields wider then they do. i.e. The first two rows display roughly two bootstrap columns wide but I would expect the third row to display at the full width.

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.To)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.To)
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subject)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subject)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Body)
    </div>
</div>
```

******* Update ********
Changed one of the fields to this

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Body" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does using container-fluid together with a col-md-12 class work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the [`form-control`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) class to your inputs as this sets the input width to be 100% which means they will completely fill the column. Unfortunately [`EditorFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx) doesn't let you do that. However, [`TextBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) does:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I have done that and still get a field that is less then 100% width.

Comment: They are 100% wide but the `col-*` classes have their own padding, is that what you mean? Look at this example: http://www.bootply.com/863hyO3jT1